Исключить пересекающиеся временные промежутки sql
Есть 2 таблицы: t1 содержит основной временной промежуток, t2 - временные промежутки внутри него, которые необходимо исключить.
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    finish_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t1 (start_date, finish_date)
VALUES ('2023-04-02', '2023-07-31');


CREATE TABLE t2 (
    exception_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    exception_finish_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t2 (exception_start_date, exception_finish_date)
VALUES 
('2023-04-15', '2023-05-01'),
--('2023-06-01', '2023-07-01');

Временные промежутки из t2 всегда целиком лежат внутри t1 и не пересекаются друг с другом. Их может быть неограниченное количество
Если исключение только одно, решение простое и может выглядеть так:
with cte as (
select *
from t1 join t2
on t1.start_date < t2.exception_start_date and t1.finish_date > t2.exception_finish_date
)
select start_date as start_date, dateadd(day, -1, exception_start_date) as finish_date
from cte
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, exception_finish_date) as start_dt, finish_date as finish_date
from cte 

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать ту же логику, но для неограниченного кол-ва исключений внутри одного интервала?
p.s. Синтаксис любой СУБД

Tstzrange есть в постгресе. Через обычный исключающий джоин выкидывай

Вам нужен именно SQL-запрос? Если можно процедурой, я бы создал временную табличку date | range_no, содержащую даты от t1.start_date до t1.finish_date, в которой поле range_no соответствовало бы диапазонам из t2, а потом сгруппировал по мин/макс дате и номеру диапазона. Да, я тот ещё изощренец и быдлокодер :)

Сгруппировал бы по номеру диапазона, а отсортировал и по дате. Прошу прощения, плохо соображаю устамши.

@OldSkull , прошу прощения - совершенно мысль не понял( а так, да - мне бы в идеале именно запрос, пусть и любого уровня сложности. Темповую таблицу можно cte'шкой заменить. На вопросы производительности можно забить временно (мне бы пока с алгоритмом расквитаться)

@eri , также совершенно не понял, о чём речь( разъясните, пожалуйста

@eri, @Lobster25. Итак, если я правильно понял задание. 1. Создаём временную таблицу, заполняем её датами от t1.start_date до t1.finish_date с интервалом 1 день (судя по примерам). 2. Удаляем в этой таблице интервалы из t2. 3. Из оставшихся дат выбираем непрерывные группы. Полагаю, это разновидность задачи "Gaps and Islands" ?

Да не.. Проще если pgsql

В общем, задача решена, написалось что-то такое
with internal_border_exception as
(
select *
from t1 join t2 on t1.start_date < t2.exception_start_date and t1.finish_date > t2.exception_finish_date
)
, final_cte as (
    -- обойдём все участки "смотря слева"
    select 
       
        case 
            when lag(exception_finish_date) over (partition by  start_date order by exception_start_date) is null then start_date
            else dateadd(day, 1, lag(exception_finish_date) over (partition by start_date order by exception_start_date)) 
        end as start_date,
        dateadd(day, -1, exception_start_date) as finish_date
    from 
        internal_border_exception
    where 
        exception_start_date is not null
    union all
    -- обработаем "крайней правый" промежуток
    select 
        case 
            when lead(exception_start_date) over (partition by  start_date order by exception_start_date) is not null then null 
            else dateadd(day, 1, exception_finish_date) 
        end as start_date,
        case 
            when lead(exception_start_date) over (partition by start_date order by exception_start_date) is not null then null 
            else finish_date 
        end as finish_date
    from 
        internal_border_exception
    where 
        exception_start_date is not null
    union all
    -- выведем интервалы, где не было внутренних исключений
    select 
        start_date, 
        finish_date
    from 
        internal_border_exception
    where 
        exception_start_date is null
)

select  start_date, finish_date
from final_cte
where start_date is not null
order by start_date;

